# How do I write a conditional function that allows a cell color to change based upon the sum of the cells in the range?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

[image]

I  need to write a conditional formatting formula that allows the colors of the range of cells I selected to change based on the sum of those cells in that same range. For example, if the sum of `C1` and `C2` falls between 21 and 99, I want `C1` and `C2` to stay red.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=(SUM(C$1:C$2)>21)*(SUM(C$1:C$2)<99)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the sum of each pair of numbers is between 21 and 99, and highlight the first cell of that pair if it is, you just need to get the first pair right and the rest will follow by the magic of relative addressing:

=and(C2+C3>21,C2+C3<=99)

[image]

But this doesn't look like your screenshot, so I have probably misunderstood the question.